# Microsoft ACS doesn't setup swarm clustering

Tags: docker-swarm, azure-container-service

After setting up multiple worker swarm cluster, When i try to login to the master node and access the list of worker nodes. It gives me an error.

```
root@swarm-master-91881543-0:~# docker node ls
Error response from daemon: This node is not a swarm manager. Use "docker swarm init" or "docker swarm join" to connect this node to swarm and try again.
root@swarm-master-91881543-0:~#
```

Comment: ...then you're running not docker swarm mode

Comment: As Markus mentioned above. Looks like you are not running in docker swarm mode

Comment: More details of the swarm cluster.

https://www.pastiebin.com/5a389f1b0fbe8

Comment: When i try doing the same from docker cloud it works without any issues..

Comment: As mentioned by Micah, use the newer SwarmMode - for launching two different products named 'swarm'. The cmdlet to do that: 
az acs create --name mySwarmCluster --orchestrator-type dockerce --resource-group myResourceGroup --generate-ssh-keys. 

Refer the document for details: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/dcos-swarm/container-service-swarm-mode-walkthrough - Do let us know if this helps.

Comment: @Ajay As i have already integrated docker cloud with azure i use dockerce as the orchestrator, My only question is why ACS does not show dockerce as an option as swarm is not working...

Attaching the screenshot https://snag.gy/KmPryc.jpg

Answer (score 0):

@biz DockerCE isn't available through the actual portal yet. You'll need to provision through the Azure CLI with the command @Ajay mentioned.